# A or B must be an irrational number proof

Tags: proof-explanation, irrational-numbers

Prove that if a and b are real numbers such that the product of ab is an irrational number, then either a or b must be an irrational number. How do I prove this?

Comment: Hint: work by contradiction.  Suppose $a,b\in \mathbb Q$.  What can you say about $ab$?

Comment: Be careful of the use of the word "*either*" as some would interpret that as implying exclusivity.  Some interpret "*either $P$ or $Q$*" as [($P$ and $\neg Q$) or ($\neg P$ and $Q$)].  The claim is false under this *exclusive or* interpretation, for counter example $\sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{3}=\sqrt{6}$ is irrational while both $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ are both irrational.  Due to the ambiguity, I recommend avoiding the use of the word entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the contrary: if a and b are rational, then their product is also rational (basic algebra $\frac{p}{q} \frac{r}{s}=\frac{pr}{qs}$)

Comment: ...noting of course that $pr$ must be an integer and that $qs$ must be an integer different than zero.  (*given the level of question, this should be a necessary step in the final complete proof, even if it seems obvious*)